# Sending large string through Ajax

Tags: ajax

So, I have this Ajax script with a PHP script in which I upload photos to the server.

This is the Ajax:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "formImage.php",
    dataType:"json",
    xhr: function()
    {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload)
        {
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progress, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    data: {info: info },
    beforeSend : function ()
    {
        //
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", success: function(result)
    {
    }
});
```

I send an array to a PHP script, when I echo out the result on the PHP script, on the console log I get `POST Content-Length exceeded`, what I am doing is I grab multiple base64 image code and concatenate it into a string but separate them with "-" which I store in `info[0]`.
I tried sending a photo at a time to the PHP script and it works, but that is really inefficient because if I have let's say 300 photos loaded, I can't do an Ajax request for each of them, I want to grab the whole 300 photos base64 code and send it as one string. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried by splitting the string to make 3 or 4 requests instead? It might be acceptable to do a bit more than 1 request no?

Comment: I haven't, but I would like to have just one request to the server, but if it can't be done, I guess I can do that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) value in PHP configuration. By default, it allows 8 MB

Answer (score 0):

Check the server settings in php.ini

```
memory_limit = ?
upload_max_filesize = ?
post_max_size = ?
```

Change Accordingly and restart the server and see

http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/protocol-of-some-php-memory-stretching-fun/